# Edge Developer Tools shows triple dots in scope and console for some fields of a variable

Tags: microsoft-edge, edge-devtools

Edge Developer Tools is showing triple dots "(...)" for a variable in the scope in the "Sources" tab.
The class variable have too many fields.
Click on triple dot shows the value of one field.

Is there an option to show all the values and thus avoid the need to Click on each of the field ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, there is no corresponding option to enable such a feature. You could send your feedback to help improve Microsoft Edge DevTools.

[Contact the Microsoft Edge DevTools team - Microsoft Edge Development | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/contact)